# Student Posittion in a Class

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-3

I'm working on a school management project. i have been able to get the total and average score for the subject . The issue i'm having is how to rank student position in a class like 1st , 2nd and so on. i have the code from the total and average score below. i'm not sure of how to go around the positioning. i'll appreciate all the assistance i can get here . Thank you

```
<?php $select_subject = $this->db->get_where('subject', 
array('class_id' =>     $class_id))->result_array();
foreach($select_subject as $key => $subject):?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $subject['name'];?></td>
<?php  $obtained_mark_query = $this->db->get_where('mark', 
array('class_id' =>$class_id, 'exam_id' => $exam_id, 
'subject_id' => $subject['subject_id'], 'student_id' => $student_id)); 
if($obtained_mark_query->num_rows() > 0){

$class_score_one      = $obtained_mark_query->row()->class_score1;
$class_score_two      = $obtained_mark_query->row()->class_score2;
$class_score_three    = $obtained_mark_query->row()->class_score3;
$exam_score           = $obtained_mark_query->row()->exam_score;
$total_score         = $class_score_one +   $class_score_two + 
$class_score_three +  $exam_score;
$average_score       = $total_score/4;

}  ?>
```

Comment: you have total score against each student ?

Comment: I have total score against each subject@ Aqib Javed. Like so..

Comment: when you get total score you can store this total score with student name in an array then sort that array and loop through it to get all the marks in descending order.

Comment: I'm trying to get the student position by ranking and not the subject. I want to get the student overall position in class and not just for the subject. I'll appreciate if you could show some codes so I understand how to go around it too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```php
$studentAverages = $this->db
  ->select('students.name AS student_name, student_id, AVG((class_score1 + class_score2 + class_score3 + exam_score) / 4) as avg_total_score')
  ->where('class_id', 2) // Class ID to get rankings for
  ->join('students', 'students.id = mark.student_id', 'left')
  ->order_by('avg_total_score', 'DESC')
  ->group_by('student_id')
  ->get('mark')
  ->result_array();

$studentRankings = [];
foreach ($studentAverages as $k=>$average) {
  $studentRankings[$average['student_id']] = $k+1;
}
```

With the above code, You have the rank of each student in its class in the $studentRankings array.
So for example if you want to know the rank of student #2 (student_id=2), Just use the code below:

```php
$studentRankings[2]
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0769a/2

Comment: Thank you so much. This was really helpful.